# Go, своя папка src на проект

Tags: golang, package

Создал пакет, переместил его в `GOPATH/src`

Все устанавливается и работает.

Но этот пакет мне нужен только в этом проекте, и тащить все в `GOPATH/src`, а таких разовых пакетов будет еще тьма, как то нет желание.

Кроме как переопределения `GOPATH` перед работой с проектом есть еще выход?

**UPD**
Вариант с `vendor` от @sanmai

```
$ pwd
/Users/borodatych/Desktop/vendoring-example-master

$ go run main.go
main.go:4:2: cannot find package "example.com/example" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/example.com/example (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/borodatych/go/src/example.com/example (from $GOPATH)

$ go env
....
GOPATH="/Users/borodatych/go"
....

$ go version
go version go1.9 darwin/amd64
```

Comment: Ничего не понял. Ваш проект должен лежать в папке, например, `$GOPATH/src/github.com/foo/bar`. В чём проблема?

Comment: @Ainar-G, акцентирую: `Но этот пакет мне нужен только в этом проекте, и тащить все в GOPATH/src, а таких разовых пакетов будет еще тьма, как то нет желание.`

Comment: В вопросе vendoring-example лежит не в ~/go, а на рабочем столе, на что go и ругается: ему никто не сказал что там нужно что-то искать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go не работает без GOPATH. По определению. Вам просто необходимо чтобы ваш код лежал хоть в каком GOPATH. Потому используйте вендоринг. [Полное описание в документации.](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Vendor_Directories)

Для этого создаёте каталог `vendor` в проекте, добавляете туда что хотите с полными путями, и готово. Ваш `GOPATH/src` будет чист и не замутнён: в нём будет только ваш основной проект. Все импорты работают как будто всё лежит в общем для всех `src`.

Логика такая: если есть импорт `example`, то сначала мы ищем его в `vendor` и только потом ищем в `GOPATH/src`. И так для каждого вложенного проекта.

Например, вот `main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "example.com/example"
)

func main() {
    example.Hello()
}
```

И вот `vendor/example.com/example/example.go`

```
package example

import "fmt"
import "test.ru/world"

func Hello() {
    fmt.Println(world.Example())
}
```

И вот `vendor/example.com/example/vendor/test.ru/world/world.go`

```
package world

func Example() string {
    return "hello world"
}
```

[Пример целиком на GitHub.](https://github.com/sanmai/vendoring-example) Все тесты на Travis проходят: [image: Build Status]

Проверить можно так:

```
$ go install github.com/sanmai/vendoring-example
$ ~/go/bin/vendoring-example
hello world
```

Или так:

```
$ go get github.com/sanmai/vendoring-example
$ go run $GOPATH/src/github.com/sanmai/vendoring-example/main.go
```

---

Наконец, у вас может быть несколько GOPATH:

```
$ echo $GOPATH
/home/username/go:/home/username/Work/Project/go
```

В этом случае может возникнуть разного рода путаница, но если вы к ней готовы - всё решаемо.

Comment: Не завелось. Пакет `libs/core` из `GOPATH/src` перенос в корне проекта в `vendor `. Что дальше делать не понятно.. `go install -vendor`, `go install -vendor ./libs/core`, `go install -vendor ./vendor/libs/core` ругается: `flag provided but not defined: -vendor
usage: install [build flags] [packages]`. И `=true` добавлял, не помогло. Дополните ответ примером, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пример добавлен.

Comment: С созданием пакета нет проблем. Я почистил `GOPATH/src` и `GOPATH/pkg` от своего пакета `libs/core`. Сейчас при старте `cannot find package "libs/core" in any of: from $GOROOT и from $GOPATH`. Установка `go install libs/core` не проходит с такими же ошибками. `libs/core` в созданной в корне проекта папке `vendor`. Скрипт запуска, если это имеет значение `go run ./Folder1/Folder2/name.go`. Импорт не трогал.

Comment: Разверните мой пример. Он точно работает на 1.8, я проверял. Какая у вас версия Go?

Comment: Зачем вы делает `go install` если пакет у вас уже есть внутри `vendor`? Чего вы хотите этим добиться?

Comment: Версия `go version go1.8.3 darwin/amd64`. Развернул ваш пример, ругается так `cannot find package "example.com/example" in any of: from $GOROOT/src/example.com/example и from $GOPATH/src/example.com/example`. Хотя в самих файлах на импорты не ругается.

Comment: Это очень странно, не находите? Может у вас с Go проблема какая.

Comment: [Вот целый рабочий пример на GitHub.](https://github.com/sanmai/vendoring-example) Все тесты на Travis проходят. Это точно не проблема в коде у меня.

Comment: Обновил под UPD, ну ей богу не заводится...

Comment: Понятно почему! Потому что проект у вас вне GOPATH. Сделайте так: `go get github.com/sanmai/vendoring-example` и после попробуйте ещё раз.

Comment: `go run $GOPATH/src/github.com/sanmai/vendoring-example/main.go`

Comment: Итого, ответ на первоначальный вопрос - `НЕТ`. Благодарю за потраченное время.

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать обёртки для go,godoc,gofmt, которые будут смотреть на путь с которым запущены, исходя из этого переопределять GOPATH каждый раз и вызывать уже настоящие команды.
У меня был такой опыт, обертки были разные - и на bash и на go. В целом работает хорошо, у меня в тот момент был отдельный GOPATH для каждого проекта. Потом с введением вендоринга стал для таскания зависимостей пользоваться им и положил всё в общий GOPATH.

Еще можете положить пакет в GOPATH/src/github.com/you/project/vendor/abc но там могут быть сложности если пакет например захотите править и при этом у вас используется что-то вроде godep.

Меня куча пакетов в GOPATH/src перестала смущать - ну лежат себе спокойно и пусть лежат.

Comment: Только не обёртки! Это ад при импорте потом.

Comment: Тут еще не только куча пакетов. Придется держать два открытых проекта - первый основной, второй с библиотеками. Или вы симлинками решаете такое? Кстати, поделитесь обертками, через upd добавьте, авось кому пригодится.

Comment: Не делитесь обёртками, пожалуйста. Хватает уже этого добра. Как напишут програм с обёртками, потом не импортировать в свой проект, не собрать штатными утилитами. Долой эти кривые велосипеды.

Comment: Обёртки: 1. потеряны 2. в массах не применимы - они мои конкретные шаблоны путей вроде бы разбирали (для простоты написания).

Answer (score 0):

Если это ваш собственный код, то лучше используйте вложенные проекты AKA модули AKA пакеты.

Например, вот `project/main.go`

```
package main

import "example"

func main() {
    example.Hello()
}
```

И вот `project/example/example.go`

```
package example

import "fmt"

func Hello() {
       fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

Так, одновременно, какие-то части будут в отдельном месте, и будут в этом же проекте. Посмотрите как устроены другие проекты или как устроена стандартная библиотека.

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае компиляция заработала только при такой структуре...
Первое. Сначала надо узнать где Ваш GOROOT.Для этого есть команда

```bash
$ go env
```

Туда нужно поместить симлинки на директории где храняться Ваши пакеджи (я привык хранить код в одном месте в какой нибудь директории на рабочем столе, по этому и создаю симлинки в GOROOT. Наверное можно хранить исходники прям в GOROOT или еще как нибудь решить эту проблемму)

Создать симлинки можно этой командой

```bash
$ ln -s <path_to_directory_with_package> <path_inside_your_GOROOT>
```

Второе. Вы должны добавит все новые package в раздел import Вашего main package файла

```go
import (
    "fmt"
    "packag1"
    "os"
    "packag2"
)
```

и в деклорации имени package, в файле с go кодом,должны быть те же имена

```go
package packag2
```

```go
package packag1
```

директории и файлы с кодом на языке go, должны называться точно так же

```bash
$ tree .
.
├── main
├── main.go
├── packag1
│   └── packag1.go
└── packag2
    └── packag2.go

2 directories, 4 files
```

не забудьте сделать симлинки

```bash
$ tree /usr/local/go/src/
/usr/local/go/src
├── packag1 -> /home/user1name/Desktop/someDeskDir/src/packag1
└── packag2 -> /home/user1name/Desktop/someDeskDir/src/packag2
```

(Я показал только те симлинки которые сам создал, обычно в GOROOT директории гораздо больше файлов)

З.Ы.
Я работаю на линукс "Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS" устанавливал GO из скачаного с сайта https://go.dev/doc/install архива go1.20.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz
На других системах может быть по другому.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

В `$GOPATH/` вы создаёте директорию под свой проект, в ней же создаёте директорию для пакета который хотите использовать только в данном проекте.

Затем в терминале переходите в папку где лежит ваш пакет, который хотите подключить, и нужно выполнить команду `go mod init имя пакета` (должно совпадать с папкой, в которой лежит файл пакета).

Затем переходите в основную папку проекта, и нужно выполнить команду `go work init`.

Затем `go work use имя пакета`.

Теперь в пакете `main` импортируете пакет `import имя пакета`.

Все, теперь этот пакет, он же модуль, будет виден только в данном проекте.

А в gopath вы можете создать сколько угодно отдельных проектов. И  ваш пакет к ним никакого отношения иметь не будет, если вы на уровне директории $gopath, конечно, go.work файл не создадите, и не определите в нем, какие модули видны и как называются.

Т.е в gopath у вас может быть proj1, proj2 и т.д., и у каждого свои пакеты main и  зависимости, которые как раз и определяются в файлах go.mod и go.work, и с помощью go.mod также можно настраивать модули, подключаемые из сети по url, но это уже немного другая история. В документации об этом подробно рассказано с примером.

Или по той же схеме размещаете свои проекты в $gopath/src, если вам так хочется, чтобы все лежало именно в source, но, если я не ошибаюсь, последняя версия по умолчанию создаёт `GOPATH=/home/user/go`, и будет ли компилятор читать ваш src сразу, или же опять GOPATH нужно менять, не могу сказать точно, попробуйте.